# My IBAction no work when i click

Tags: ios, ibaction

I create a button in my mainViewController. The button should go to the page ItaliaViewController but my button does not work.

Here is my code

```
   -(IBAction)openRubric:(id)sender
    {
      ItaliaViewController *italia = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rubric_italia"];
    }
```

please help me

Comment: can you please tel us how to connect IBAction of Button with your Button Outlate.?

Comment: via the connections inspector on the storyborad

Comment: check that is Connect with TouchUpInsed or what..?

Comment: you are just instantiating a VC but presenting it nowhere. What else do you you expect?

Comment: yes i connect with TouchUpInsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to present your new view controller, in your case z ItaliaViewController. 
use this

```
      [self presentViewController:italia animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code does not mean that the new view controller will be displayed because you have to call `presentViewController` function to call the new controller but first concern is to check if the function is getting called at all or not. Call it like this

```
[self presentViewController:italia animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Either write an `NSLog` in the button code or place a debug point to test if the function is getting called. If it does not gets called, make sure you have joined the function to the button in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First put an NSLog inside the button action. if it print something on button action, it mean your button is working properly and you are making a mistake during navigating view controller if not then check button connection in XIB

```
NSLog(@"button action is working);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *newStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ViewName" bundle:nil];
ViewName *firstvc = [newStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self presentViewController:firstvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Don't forget to import the header file of the Stroyboard view into the header or implementation file of the view you are opening it from.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above you have to perform some steps to figure out about issue

1-check whether UIButton is connected via `Outlet` with action Event ToupUpInside

2- you push your view in stack by navigation or as suggested above with self presentViewController`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. it works.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)openRubric:(id)sender
{
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Italia"];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```